# Looking for ancient kernel source

Tags: linux-kernel, source, header-file

I'm looking for an specific old kernel source namely 2.6.26.5 to build an exact replicate of an cross toolchain for an embedded target. Unfortunately all I can find is 2.6.26 in the kernel.org archives.

Is there any difference between their headers? Where can I get them?

Comment: Is this a distro kernel? If so, go to that distro and look for the sources in that archive. For e.g. Debian you could start with archive.debian.org.

Comment: Unfortunately no. It seems to be handcrafted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why this version is no longer in the kernel.org FTP archives, but you can pull it from git:

```
$ git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/stable/linux-stable.git
$ cd linux-stable
$ git checkout -f v2.6.26.5
$ head -4 Makefile 
VERSION = 2
PATCHLEVEL = 6
SUBLEVEL = 26
EXTRAVERSION = .5
```

I needed the `-f` option in the `checkout` command here for reasons I cannot figure out. It claims that — immediately after the `clone` — I have local modifications to my tree, and it's trying to save me from throwing them away by switching branches. Bizarre.

Annnyway... Building against generic 2.6.26 headers probably isn't a problem. The changes are likely things which affect kernel *functionality* but not any APIs. Thus, the generic headers will export the same APIs.

If you're running a kernel with changes made by your embedded Linux distro provider, those should not affect any ABIs. The main thing you need to do to get the correct ABI is use the correct cross-compilation toolchain.